# call var value from a function into a tkinter label

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter

im trying to output the value of `fSpeed` or `FastSpeed` into a Tkinter label, but it doesnt want to call the value out of the function `motorSpeed()` and then into the label, however it does with printing out the command into the console. any ideas?

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

fSpeed = 0
FastSpeed = 0.001  # default Speed

var = StringVar(master)

labelPreset = Label(master, text="Presets:")
labelPreset.pack(side=LEFT)
options = {"20cm": 200, "30cm": 300, "40cm": 400, "50cm": 500, "60cm": 600}
option = OptionMenu(master, var, *options.keys())
option.pack(side=LEFT)


def getBauteil():
    print("value is", options[var.get()])
    motorSpeed()
    # master.quit()


def motorSpeed():
    if var != 0:
        FastSpeed = options[var.get()]
        global fSpeed
        fSpeed = FastSpeed / 2
        print(FastSpeed)
        print(fSpeed)
        return FastSpeed
        return fSpeed


button = Button(master, text="OK", command=getBauteil)
button.pack(side=LEFT)

label1 = Label(master, textvariable=var)
label1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
label2 = Label(master, text=fSpeed)
label2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

master.title("Smart Spray Booth - Configuration")
master.configure(bg="grey80")
master.geometry("300x300")
mainloop()
```

Comment: add `master.update_idletasks()` in the `motorSpeed` function

Comment: it still does not update label2  :( But it works if i insert the label2 into the `getBauteil()` function. the problem with that is that it always makes a new label when i press on the button..

Comment: The label updates for me. I do not see any problem in the code. And how do you generate new `Label` when there is not label definition in the `getBauteil` function